# How to disable desktop composition while gaming in fullscreen?

Tags: release-freya, window-management, desktop, games, graphics

I'm using elementary OS Freya 0.3.1 and would like to disable compositing while gaming. I'm playing CSGO (Linux port, not Windows version using Wine) and unlike on my Windows 10, it's lagging a lot. I would also like to disable hotcorners while in fullscreen gaming, as it goes into multitasking view randomly.

Comment: It seems to be a bug here https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1380272

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script to launch the game that disable hot corners before launching game then enable them back after closing the game.

Example, `launch_game.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Make backup of the settings
dconf dump /org/pantheon/desktop/gala/behavior/ > ~/.hotcorner.dconf

# Disable hot corner (just reset,as they are disabled by default)
dconf reset /org/pantheon/desktop/gala/behavior/hotcorner-topright
dconf reset /org/pantheon/desktop/gala/behavior/hotcorner-topleft
dconf reset /org/pantheon/desktop/gala/behavior/hotcorner-bottomright
dconf reset /org/pantheon/desktop/gala/behavior/hotcorner-bottomleft

# Launch the game
putyourgamecommandhere

# Load back your hot corner settings
dconf load /org/pantheon/desktop/gala/behavior/ < ~/.hotcorner.dconf
```